# "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'weekslast'" for a copied data frame but not for the original data frame

Tags: python, copy, attributeerror

Does the copy of a data frame behave differently than the copied data frame?

```
d_copy = d.copy()
```

If I run any command on the variables in d_copy, it gives me the following error:

> " AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'weekslast'"

, while if I use the same commands on d, it does not. What can be the reason?

Here's an example:

```
type(d.weekslast)
Out[9]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

while this is what I get if I run the same one on the d_copy:

```
type(d_copy.weekslast)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
> type(d_copy.weekslast)
>
> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'weekslast'

Comment: Can you show us exactly what you are doing? I can't replicate your issue: `df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1} for i in range(3)]); c = df.copy(); c.a` returns a `Series`

Comment: I'm trying to work with a copied data frame but I can;t run anything on the new copied data frame. I always get the same error. Whereas all commands run perfectly on the original one

Comment: Ok, can you give us the [smallest example possible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) required to reproduce your issue formatted into your question? Sounds like this should probably be 3-4 lines of code